# Any library to exchange messages (pub/sub) through network on android?

Tags: android, network-programming, message-queue, publish-subscribe

I'm building a Server/Client app on android. There're many clients will connect to server using wifi, server will broadcast update messages to clients, and clients will send query message to server.

I implemented it with threads and sockets, it just looks too complex to me. Is there any library I can use so I don't need to care about stuff at low level (e.g. check connection alive and reconnect if necessary)?

Update: The deploy environment has only local network (WIFI), no access to Internet.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)?

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device. This could be a lightweight message telling your app there is new data to be fetched from the server (for instance, a movie uploaded by a friend), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly).
>
> The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to the target Android application running on the target device. GCM is completely free no matter how big your messaging needs are, and there are no quotas.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it requires internet access, correct? The problem is my deploy environment has no access to internet, only local network.

Comment: @Jan It's going to be complicated then. You can look at existing solutions like RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ and the like and that will help, but probably will still require a lot of work to get going.